# Process all inflight changes and commit the transaction on shutdown in apache Camel

Tags: spring-boot, transactions, apache-camel, application-shutdown

I have 4 routed defined in my camel application. The first route gets all the record_ids (primary_key) and sends it to second route one by one using Camel's splitter. The second route fetched the records from DB and process them further. Everything runs in a single transaction using Camel's "transacted()" method. 
So is there any way I can process all the messages before shutdown? I read about [graceful-shutdown](http://people.apache.org/~dkulp/camel/graceful-shutdown.html) but how can I let my transaction commit because
as soon as I shutdown the application my EntityManager get destroyed which is actually managed by SpringBoot?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Camel and Spring Boot do you use?

Comment: Camel 2.19.3 with spring boot 1.5.7

Comment: Try with 2.20.0 as we improved the start/shutdown when using spring/spring-boot